# Using Substring to retreive part of string from a column and dealing with

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column I have to work with to get part of a string. I know ultimately the database needs to be fixed. However, I don't have any other options at this point.

The column ReceiptText contains a string like this:

> Parthenons AS 0183 OSLO  BAX: 604847-71613681 12/11/2018 04:22  AVSTEMMING  OVERF: 390  01-BankAxept      58 NOK          8513,00   03-VISA            5 NOK          1074,00   04-MASTERCARD      5 NOK          1636,00   14-MAESTRO         1 NOK            79,00   -------------------- INNSAMLET         69 TOTAL       11302,00  KORTAVTALER UTEN OMSETNING SKRIVES IKKE UT.

I need to be able to just retrieve the `79,00`. The criteria is based on finding `14-MAESTRO` and `INNSAMMLET`. This is what I wrote:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ReceiptText, CHARINDEX('MAESTRO', ReceiptText), CHARINDEX('INNSAMLET',
ReceiptText) - CHARINDEX('MAESTRO', ReceiptText) + Len('INNSAMLET'))

From DaysTakings
```

This is the result:

> MAESTRO         1 NOK            79,00   -------------------- INNSAMLET

I just need the `79` but I can't figure out how to narrow it down further.

Comment: What is the pattern of fields in your string? You need to know that in order to pull out complete elements.I see multiple currency (NOK) values - are you certain you know that you only want the one?

Comment: what version of SQL server are you on? 2012, 2014, 2016?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [PATINDEX()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to extract float value. Try using a similar query:

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING(
            SUBSTRING(ReceiptText, CHARINDEX('MAESTRO', ReceiptText) + LEN('MAESTRO'), CHARINDEX('INNSAMLET',ReceiptText) - 
                                                     CHARINDEX('MAESTRO', @ReceiptText) - Len('INNSAMLET') - Len('MAESTRO')),
                      PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][,][0-9]%',SUBSTRING(ReceiptText, CHARINDEX('MAESTRO', ReceiptText) + LEN('MAESTRO'), 
                                                     CHARINDEX('INNSAMLET',ReceiptText) - CHARINDEX('MAESTRO', ReceiptText) - Len('INNSAMLET') - Len('MAESTRO'))),5)
```

Result

> 79.00

Note that this will only work if the number format is `[0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9]`.